# How to use textarea and other elements inside materialize md-container?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, materialize

I have `readonly` list of emails that i wanted to display in the field so I am trying to use `textarea` inside `md-input-container` using angularjs `ng-repeat` but it throws error `only one input allowed in the md-input-container`. I am new to materialize any idea what is better way to achieve this approach using AngularMaterial Ui ?

main.html

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin style="height:100px; overflow: scroll;">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <div><label>Bcc</label></div>
        <textarea flex="100" ng-repeat="email in notifyCtrl.bcc" name="email" readonly="true">
                </textarea>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.notifyCtrl.bcc = ["abc@domain.com","xyz@domain.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

since you need to show multiple emails in a field I recommend using `<md-chips>` instead of the textarea

```
<div layout layout-sm="column" layout-margin >
                <md-chips flex ng-model="notifCtrl.bcc" class="md-primary" readonly="true" placeholder="Bcc" delete-button-label="Remove Tag" delete-hint="Press delete to remove tag" secondary-placeholder="Bcc">
                </md-chips> 
 </div>
```

Comment: How would you make `md-chips` scroll in case large amount of data ?

Comment: chips don't have scroll it will dynamically increase the height. you can set max height to chip container and add a scroll to that

Comment: i do not see data in `md-chips` field using your answer

Comment: are we using your answer inside `md-input-container` or we dont need container ?

Comment: no not inside `md-input-container` it's parent div or something

Comment: placeholder has styling issue with `md-chips` field values , can we use label instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Virtual Repeat from angular material UI if that suits your need:

**HTML:**

```
     <md-content layout="column">
         <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
            <div md-virtual-repeat="email in notifyCtrl.bcc" class="repeated-item" flex="">
              {{email}}
            </div>
        </md-virtual-repeat-container>
      </md-content>

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage #vertical-container {
  height: 292px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px; }

.virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage .repeated-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px; }

.virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage md-content {
  margin: 16px; }

.virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage md-virtual-repeat-container {
  border: solid 1px grey; }

.virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage .md-virtual-repeat-container .md-virtual-repeat-offsetter div {
  padding-left: 16px; }
```

**JS:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app',['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.notifyCtrl = {};
      $scope.notifyCtrl.bcc = ['abc@domain.com','xyz@domain.com'];  
});
})();
```

Attaching a working code pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNBjLx

Source : 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: I have modified my code and also added a working code pen here